# change jQuery UI Dialog button as a simple link?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a custom button defined in the jquery ui dialog box:

```
$("#myDlg").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'My Custom Link': function () {
                alert('my custom message');
            },
            'Close': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

I would like to show the button 'My Custom Link' as an html link rather than with the default button style. How can I do that? thanks.

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118748/jquery-ui-dialog-link-instead-of-button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default jQuery options doesn't support adding links.. however you can add anything you want to the wrapper.. See below,

```
$(function() {
    $("#myDlg").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Close': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    })
    .parent()
    .find('.ui-dialog-buttonset')
    .prepend('<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="myCustomLink">My Custom Link</a>');

    $('#myCustomLink').click(function () {
        alert('my custom message');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fGHLZ/1/)

Comment: this is exactly what i want! thanks so much for the demo also. +1